# double page title

Tags: theme-development, title, wp-title

I have my page title on the home 'My siteMy site'. and other pages as 'Page title | My siteMy site'. I have checked in the header.php file for my theme and it look okay

```
<title><?php wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?></title>
```

I also checked in the settings for the site titly and it remains 'My site'

I have done my research on repeated titles and most people seem to have this problem because of a SEO plugin overrides the title. In my case I do not have any SEO plugins, below you can see a list of enabled plugins on my site:

1. Bootstrap 3 Shortcodes
2. Contact Form 7
3. Custom Theme Options
4. Food and Drink Menu
5. Instagram Feed
6. Ketchup Shortcodes Pack
7. Meta Slider

None of them are supposed to have any affect on page titles, I tried disabling them to see one of them affects it and I haven't noticed any change. Has anyone else faced a similar problem before. Are there other things that my overwrite my page titles?

Comment: Try the new, recommended syntax - remove the `<title />` tag from your `header.php` and add `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` to your `functions.php`

Comment: check your theme for any filters on `'wp_title'`.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your comments, I have looked into a possible repeated question, however I did not find it as helpful as the last comment by @michel after looking into the functions.php file I found this filter

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'burger_wp_title', 10, 2 );
function burger_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 50;
}
```

Which I have gotten rid of and now I no longer can see duplicated site name in the page title.